# How to make Multiple select combine with input text

Tags: html, css

how to combine multiple select with input. so if there is no option in the option, we can add new options to the multiple select.[image]

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: If bootstrap is acceptable, refer : https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/bootstrap-multiselect/#basic-example

Answer (score 0):

Just add a attribute multiple within select tag
See this code for your Reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>

</body>
</html>
```